# ¿Porqué me sale un error al instalar Intervention en Laravel 5.8 con Composer?

Tags: laravel-5, php7, composer

Cuando intento instalar Intervention en Laravel 5.8 con el siguiente comando:

composer require intervention/image intervention/imagecache

me da el siguiente error:

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.

[image: error Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.]

Así que luego lo intente con la opcion --with-all-dependencies y ahora me da el siguiente error que no puedo resolver para instalar Intervetion en Laravel

[image: Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1]

In PackageManifest.php line 122:

Undefined index: name

Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1

Ojalá  puedan ayudarme o aconsejarme como resolverlo o donde encontrar más información sobre estos errores, de antemano gracias por su atención

Comment: comproba la versión de composer y de laravel ( downgrade composer a 1.x o uprade laravel a 5.8.38 ) en mi caso el downgrade composer me ha funcionado con un laravel 5.4.x y el upgrade laravel con un 5.6.x, https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/9340#issuecomment-716210369

Comment: * para cambiar la version de composer a 1.x `composer self-update --1`, a 2.x `composer self-update --2`

Comment: hola y gracias por tus comentarios, ya probé degradando Composer pero no funcionó y la verdad no quiero cambiar la versión de Laravel por el momento.

Answer (score 0):

Ya quedo resuelto:

Aquí esta la instalación de intervention/image

[image: Intervention image]

y aquí la de intervention/imagecache

[image: Intervention cache]

No supe finalmente a ciencia cierta cual era el problema, solo hice los cambios que me comentaste @alo Malbarez con Composer me regrese a la versión 1 de Composer y no funciono, luego volví a la versión 2 y al hacer esto me apareció un error en el proyecto debido que se genero por los cambios de las versiones, así que investigue como eliminar ese nuevo error y encontré que se elimina con el siguiente comando:

> composer update

después de esto pude volver a ejecutar mi proyecto y por necio un día después volví a intentar instalar el paquete Intervention como se ve en las imágenes y alegremente funciono esta vez. Así que creo que la actualización con

> composer update

fue lo que soluciono el problema :)